# Why are posts on my Google+ Page for Business only visible when I'm logged in?

Tags: google-plus

I have been posting some articles to Google+ the last week , but I can only see the posts when I'm logged in to my account.

If I logout and search for my page, no posts are shown. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you didn't post to a circle/the circles you intended to.

When you create a post, you are given the option to post to one or more circles. The default is "Public". If you can't see the posts when you are logged out, you most likely posted to a circle other than "public".

[image: posting modal]