# My posts in community is visible only to me

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-communities

I joined 2 Google+ photo communities and made 2 posts with photos. I can see them on the community page and my profile, but other people don't see them on the community page. Also, when logged out, I don't see my posts on the community pages either.

Why is it so?

Comment: Check this similar thread http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/why-are-posts-on-my-google-page-for-business-only-visible-when-im-logged-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posts are probably awaiting moderation by the community admins.